Can't Find Delta Table Sink From Data Factory in Databricks
While I am technical as a data analyst, working in the cloud is fairly new to me as well as administration of databases.  I'm trying to play around a bit on azure to get more used to it, but I'm confused why I can't see a table that I'm supposed to be creating.
I have a really simple ADF data flow.  It gets a json payload from an API and is supposed to sink it to a delta table on ADLS Gen2.  The files do get sinked, I can see the parquet and log files, and everything seems to work.  Except when I open up Azure Databricks and explore my catalog nothing is there
What am I doing wrong so that I can't view the inline delta table I created in Databricks?



You can check a  Catalog table using a three tier identifier (select * from <catalog_name>.<database_name>.<table_name>).

Using the inline sink to the Delta ataset I only reference a location on ADLS.  For example my folder path is kc311/311Delta.  How would I find the path for that table?  I added pictures to my post showing my sink path.

Writing to ADLS gen2 doesn't mean a table gets created in the Databricks metastore. Basically all the sink is doing is writing files to the storage account in the delta lake format, you need to register it as a table in Databricks separately.
If you've mounted the storage account you can use the path to the table, otherwise you can use the abfss URI (granted the permissions are setup).
CREATE TABLE your_table USING delta LOCATION '/mnt/kc311/311Delta';

Please see the docs on creating (external) tables, and example of working with abfss (different from your use case though).

Understood that makes sense thank you.  And if I wanted a no code way to create the table I would use the Copy data activity in data factory?

There is no standard way for ADF to create the table in the databricks metastore. With a copy activity you can copy data in csv, parquet etc (not in delta format), these will once again simply be files in the storage account.
